# Opening a dialog box in jquery with php content

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to open a chat portal in a dialog using jquery.

Here is my code

```
<img class="chatBtn" id="chat_btn" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px" src="images/colored_livecha.png" alt="" width="80" height="33" />

jQuery('.chatBtn').click(function() {
  var dlg = jQuery('#chat_btn').dialog({
    autoOpen: 'false',
    modal: 'true',
    minHeight:'300px',
    minWidth: '300px'
  });

  dlg.load('chat.php', function(){
    dlg.dialog('open');
  });
});
```

However on click nothing happens. What amendments are required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to wrap that in a script tag.

```
 <script>
jQuery('.chatBtn').click(function() 
{

  var dlg = jQuery('#chat_btn').dialog(
    {
 autoOpen: 'false',
  modal: 'true',
  minHeight:'300px',
  minWidth: '300px'
  });

dlg.load('chat.php', function(){
         dlg.dialog('open');
     });
});
 </script>
```

Another question, is jQuery included in the head or somewhere in the page?

Comment: I have a separate jquery file in which all these functions are within jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{ and yes jquery is added in header

Comment: i can't get it work, nothing happens when i click on it. if i put alert('ok') it works

Comment: Now the javascript is at least running. Do you get any javascript errors? Have you opened developer tools? F12 in chrome, or in firefox u'll need to install firebug.

Comment: Well it gives TypeError : Undefined is not a function.

Comment: can you run this in the console of the developer tools: `jQuery` What does it return? Also, dialog is part of jQuery UI I do believe. Have you included this as well?

Comment: src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js">this is added, can u let me know what else needs to be added, i am not expert of jquery

Comment: You might need to add `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js` but please check `jquery` in the console for me. To get to the console its F12 and then look for the tab that says console, type jquery and hit enter

Comment: itsays ReferenceError: jquery is not defined, I have already added above jquery library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56062/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-muhammad-umar).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to get the information in the database using PHP, and populate the UI tables like that. The major downside would be loading time. If you find that the page is taking too long to load, then you may want to look into jQuery's .ajax()

Comment: its a chat panel. I want to open it in a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference jquery library :

1. href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css.
2. src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js".
3. src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js".
4. rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css".